# Mixed POST and GET submission

Tags: 6, forms

I am building a page with a filtered table of data. I would like the filter to submit the date field information in the URL, while the **op**, **form_build_id** and the other Drupal internal fields are kept as post.

Currently if I set the method to *GET* all the form fields are put on the URL, naturally.

Mostly, I want to do this to keep things neat for the user.

I have read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749406/post-and-get-at-the-same-time-in-php) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447346/use-get-and-post-in-the-same-form?lq=1), related questions but:

1. They don't have the benefits/constraints of using the Drupal Form API.
2. They use static/preset *GET* values.

Is there any way that mixing *POST* and *GET* in Drupal 6 can be achieved?

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749406/post-and-get-at-the-same-time-in-php for a primer before continuing...

Comment: Read it. I don't quite understand the question there. From what I can tell it's pretty much the same as what I want - send GET and POST in one request. But if the GET variables are in the action then they can't be dynamic, right? My GET values need to come from the form.

Comment: I have found a solution that seems to work and will post it as an answer as soon I have tested it.

Comment: What you are asking for makes no sense, and would violate the HTTP protocol, as explained in the accepted answer to the question Clive linked to.

Comment: I think I should be saying a *query string* rather than *GET*. Is that still a violation of the protocol - using a *query string* on a *POST* request? @Henry also asked the same question, as a comment, in [another, similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954831/i-cant-use-get-and-post-at-the-same-time-in-php#comment29363467_7954883).